# Kotlin: Can I access a nested array from inside another array?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

This may be a dumb question, but I have an array:

```
var testarray = arrayOf(0,0,arrayOf(7,5,2))
```

So I tried to access the second array by typing `testarray[2][1]`. However, this throws an error:

```
error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun <@OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map<out Int, ???>.get(key: Int): ??? defined in kotlin.collections
testarray[2][1]
^
error: no get method providing array access
testarray[2][1]
```

Is there a way to access the nested array?

Answer (score 3):

Your outer array contains Ints, and an array. So its actual declared type (that you could specify, or could let the IDE specify for you), is `Array<Serializable>`.

A `Serializable` could be anything. The compiler doesn't know that the element at index 2 happens to be an array. So it can't let you use the `[]` operator on it. You need to cast the element to an array to be able to do that:

```
println((testarray[2] as Array<Int>)[1])
```

That would fix the compilation issue, but not the design issue. Using arrays in general is already a smell, but using arrays containing mixed types is an even bigger smell. You should reconsider your design.

Comment: So use MutableLists instead in this case? Or would there be a better datatype in this case?

Comment: I don't know enough about your use-case to recommend anything concrete. In general you should favor collections over arrays, and immutable collections over mutable ones.

Comment: I need to be able to modify the values inside the object, but I do not need to change the length.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that you should rethink your design as JB Nizet already said.

You could do that by generalizing your array to an array of arrays like this:

```
val testArray = arrayOf(arrayOf(0), arrayOf(0), arrayOf(7, 5, 2))
```

which would ensure that you can get and set elements like this:

```
testArray[2][1]
testArray[2][0] = 4
```

---

As long as you just want to access the elements in the fashion you described keeping your design you could create a (local) operator extension function [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading) on `Serializable` like this:

```
operator fun Serializable.get(i: Int) = (this as? Array<*>)?.get(i) ?: this

val a = arrayOf(0, 0, arrayOf(7,5,2))

println(a[1][0]) // 0
println(a[2][1]) // 5
```

Comment: That's definitely feasible. Actually I like this idea the more I think about it. If it's a 2d array, I should have to pass the array element anyway.

Comment: I'm getting 'error: no set method providing array access' whenever I try to change the values in the array